# get_avatar() as backround image

Tags: page-template

```
<div class="kkk" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_avatar_url(); ?>')"></div>
```

I want to make to appear my avatar as a backround image in this code, but it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to say exactly what the problem is with your code, but...

There is at least one major flaw - you don’t pass any param to [`get_avatar_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/), but first param for that function is required and should contain ID or email. To be precise:

> **$id_or_email** (mixed) (Required) The Gravatar to retrieve a URL for.
>   Accepts a user_id, gravatar md5 hash, user email, WP_User object,
>   WP_Post object, or WP_Comment object.